# sudo -u userX python3 messing up python PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, sudo

I have a shell script to start some python scripts. I need to start the python script with a different user, therefore I am chinging the user via `sudo -u userX`, but somehow this statement messes the `PYTHONPATH` up. 
Starting only one python script works, but when I try to import scripts from the same dir, they get not found.

The shell script:

```
cd $1
sudo -u userX PYTHONPATH=. python3 $2
```

As you can see I tried to add the current dir manually to `PYTHONPATH`, but still same error.

My python script:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)

from second import calc

#output of the script:
# $ ['', '/var/www/html/assignments_rest/EvaluationServer/sandbox/proc_0/1', ...]
# $ Traceback (most recent call last): File "first.py", line 4, in <module> from second import calc 
# $ ImportError: No module named 'second'
```

When I add the path in the python script its working fine:

```
sys.path.append(".")
print(sys.path)

from second import calc

# $ ['', '/var/www/html/assignments_rest/EvaluationServer/sandbox/proc_0/1', ...]
# $ doing stuff no erros
```

What really confuses me, is the `sys.path` seams to be the same, but imports work only after `sys.path.append(".")`. But for my purpose adding dir in the python script itself is no option. So I have to add that before starting the python script itself.

Any idea how to solve this?

---

**Edit 1:**

I am running a Server where students can upload their python script. The scripts are executed and then evaluated. For security reason, I created a "sandbox" (`../sandbox/proc_0/..`), I copy all the scripts there, and than execute them with a different user `userX` how only has read/write/executer rights for this directory and nowhere else. The shell scripts I call from my backend (see above) are located outside of the sandbox.

The user `userX` is a minimal User with no `home` directory or password.

---

**Edit 2:**
Here is an example when I execute the scripts directly from the shell, I changed the director to `../sandbox/proc_0/1/`. This how the dir looks like:

```
|--first.py
|--second.py
```

Running the following works perfectly:

```
$ mb@assignments:../sandbox/proc_0/1$ python3 first.py
$ Geben Sie eine Zßhl ein: 3
$ Das Ergebniss ist 2.3 für a = 3
```

Running the same but with changing the user:

```
$ mb@assignments:../sandbox/proc_0/1$ sudo -u eval python3 first.py
$ Traceback (most recent call last):
$   File "first.py", line 1, in <module>
$     from second import calc
$ ImportError: No module named 'second'
```

Adding the `PYTHONPATH`:

```
$ mb@assignments:../sandbox/proc_0/1$ sudo -u eval PYTHONPATH=/var/www/html/assignments_rest/EvaluationServer/sandbox/proc_0/1 python3 first.py
$ Traceback (most recent call last):
$   File "first.py", line 1, in <module>
$     from second import calc
$ ImportError: No module named 'second'
```

When I am adding the tow lines `sys.path.append("."); print(sys.path)` to `first.py`, it's working in every case.

Comment: So in your first `print`, the path already contains `.` ?

Comment: btw is the user you want to run the script as really called `eval` ? That could cause some confusion :)

Comment: @etene yes and yes i changed the username to prevent confusion

Comment: Just make the PYTHONPATH explicit by pointing it to the full path of the relevant directory. Much clearer.

Comment: @Evert I tried this before, but still the same error

Comment: I can't see  where you have quoted the actual error. Lets see that. However, changing user might change the PATH to the PATH of the different user. As Evert suggested, possibly just make the Path fully explicit.

Comment: @nerak99 I have edit my post to make it more clear.

Comment: @nerak99 As I have already mentioned passing the explicit path is not working, this would be `... PYTHONPATH=$1` in my script, with `$1 = /var/www/html/assignments_rest/EvaluationServer/sandbox/proc_0/1`

Comment: 'not working' is not the same as 'the error message'. Which could arrive at the console or in a log somewhere. The error message is very useful in diagnosing the problem. I think that what you might be doing is changing the PATH in one user but using the PATH of the other one.

Comment: Is `setenv` or `env_reset` enabled in `sudoers`? Is `PYTHONPATH` in `env_check` or `env_delete`? Also, can you print out `os.environ` from inside Python and see if `PYTHONPATH` is there? If not, then sudo is filtering out the variable (or, conceivably, the link-loader is before it even gets to `sudo`). In which case: read the manpage on `sudo` and `sudoers`, read your `sudoers` file, and look for help on SuperUser or a Unix-specific site rather than SO if you can't figure it out.

Comment: Also, is `os.getcwd()` what you expect?

Comment: @abarnert I am not sure what you mean with the first to sentences (I don't have to much knowledge about linux). The `PYTHONPATH` is included in `os.environ` and it also point to the correct dir. `os.getcwd()` is also pointing to the corret dir.

Comment: Are the modules you're trying to import in the same directory as the script you're calling ? Can you give an example value for `$2` in your shell script ?

Comment: yes they are, and `$2` is the name of the python script for example `first.py`

Comment: I tried to reproduce your setup (i.e. a shell script that takes a directory name and a script name as arguments, cds to the directory, and calls the script), and couldn't reproduce the error. There's got to be more to this. If you could post a minimal working example reproducing the issue that would definitely clear things up.

Comment: The setup is a little bit complicated. On my local development machine, I can not reproduce the issue. I try to explain the setup in a new edit in my post.

Comment: There must be something missing, I am completely unable to reproduce your issue on my system (Python 3.6.5rc1, sudo 1.8.21p2). If you run a shell as the `eval` user and try to execute the script, what happens ?

Comment: I get the same import error, I had a look at the `PYTHONPATH`. If I add the dir to the with `PYTHONPATH=.` before starting the script, the absolute path gets added. If I add the dir at the begining of the python script, only `.` is added.The problem must have to do something with the user rights. Because `eval` does not have access to the parent dirs. Maybe that's the reason.